# Ajax does not retrieves data in partial view in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I my below code i am calling partial view with ajax but when i click on the link of product Name the description of that product is not retrieved through ajax and error of ajax executes. I am retrieving the details of items selected by user on the same page but it is not retrieved. Please give any suggestion where is the issue arising because i am new to MVC. thanks...

Create.cshtml

```
@model List<PartialView.Models.tbl_product>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create</title>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.msg').click(function () {
                var id = this.id;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Category/Display",
                    data: { data: id },
                    success: function (mydata) {
                        $("#link").empty().append(mydata);
                    },
                    error: function (mydata) { alert("error"); },
                    type: "POST"
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{ 
<a class="msg" href="#" id="@item.ProductId">@item.ProductName</a>
}
<div id="link">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

ClicksUs.cshtml (PartialView)

```
@model List<PartialView.Models.tbl_product>

@foreach(var items in Model)
{ 
    @items.ProductDesc
}
```

CategoryController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PartialView.Models;

namespace PartialView.Controllers
{
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        dbEntities dbentity = new dbEntities();

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View(dbentity.tbl_product.ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult Display(int data)
        {
            var query = dbentity.tbl_product.First(c => c.ProductId == data);
            return PartialView("ClicksUC", query);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: can you post what do you get from your ajax call

Comment: Display method get the id suppose if i click on the link whose id is 2 then Display method is getting that id and query retrieves the details of the item whose id is 2 but when the control in the ajax function goes into error block and if i print alert(mydata) it print [object Object] please give any suggestion..

Comment: to return partial View with json: return View("PartialViewName",jsonData)

Comment: On this line `return PartialView("ClicksUC", query);` name of the partial view is `ClicksUC`. But you said before the name was `ClicksUs.cshtml`. I think it is misspelled.

Comment: Its ClicksUC.cshtml i think there is any error in ajax code, ecause the value is returned from the controller method properly, but the partial view is not updated, it does not show any record when i click on link..

Comment: In that case you are not getting your id right. It is like `$('#element').attr('id');`. In your case `$(this).attr('id');`. And please update the name of the view to avoid confusion.

Comment: this function is getting the id of the anchor tag which is clicked suppose i clicked on <a id="2"> Product name</a> then this id is passed to the method and the details of the record is retrieved from the database when i put breakpoint at return PartialView("ClicksUC", query); this line it displays the particular items details but i think that ajax is not getting back those details and updating the html content....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Details` controller action selects a single element here (because you are calling `.First()`):

```
public ActionResult Display(int data)
{
    var query = dbentity.tbl_product.First(c => c.ProductId == data);
    return PartialView("ClicksUC", query);
}
```

So the type of the query variable is `tbl_product` and not `List<tbl_product>`.

On the other hand your partial's model is `List<PartialView.Models.tbl_product>` which is obviously wrong.

Your partial's model should be a single `tbl_product`:

```
@model PartialView.Models.tbl_product
@Model.ProductDesc
```

Oh and what others said about the typo in your partial view name.

Comment: +1 darin, i was editing to add that, but you said it 1st (regarding singular table in view) ;)

Answer (score 0):

there are three issues in the code that you could address.

- One is a typo (the partialview is called ClicksUS, NOT ClicksUC),
- the other is related to the way you return the data
- the third is that you use the `type: "POST"`, you should change this to `type: "GET"`.

try changing the code to:

```
public ActionResult Display(int data)
{
    // using First() would have caused you an error in the view if not found
    // still not perfect below, but a step closer 
    var query = dbentity.tbl_product.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ProductId == data);
    // You had ClicksUC, rather than ClicksUS
    return PartialView("ClicksUS", query);
}
```

I'd also strongly suggest that you create a `ViewModel` for your data, rather than passing the objects from the database as this will allow you to control exactly the data that should be viewed and how it should be formatted etc.

**[edit]**
Also, as Darin says, based on a single row being retruned, you should change your partial view model type to:

```
@model PartialView.Models.tbl_product
```

Comment: correct :-) - firstordefault is what i'd meant- sunday morning maddness.. forgive!