# Getting Json Data from ajax in mvc and partial view is not called

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

This question is related to my previous question, i want to display the details of product on the same page, for that i have used Ajax and partial View but the partial view is not rendering and only the Json Data is Updated in the div through Ajax, I dont want to display json data but only the product Desciption in text format the following code i have used, and the output is also shown, when i click on product1 it displays details regarding with product1 and when i click on product2 it shows details regarding with product2 and so on, In the controller method search i have called view, but that view is also not called. Please help to sort these problems. thanks

CategoryController.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using PartialView.Models;


namespace PartialView.Controllers
{
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        dbEntities dbentity = new dbEntities();

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View(dbentity.tbl_product.ToList());
        }

        public JsonResult Search(int data)
        {
            var query = dbentity.tbl_product.Where(c => c.ProductId == data);
            return Json(query,"Record Found");
            //return View("ClickUC", query);
        }
    }
}
```

Seach.cshtml

```
@model List<PartialView.Models.tbl_product>

@foreach(var items in Model)
{ 
    @items.ProductDesc
}
```

Create.cshtml

```
@model List<PartialView.Models.tbl_product>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Create</title>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.msg').click(function () {
                var id = this.id;
                alert(id);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Category/Search",
                    data: { data: id },
                    success: function (mydata) {
                        alert("success");
                        $('#link').empty().append(mydata);
                    },
                    error: function (mydata) { alert("error"); alert(mydata); },
                    type: 'POST'
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{ 
<a class="msg" href="#" id="@item.ProductId">@item.ProductName</a>
}
<div id="link">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

View Product Details : Product 1   Product2

[{"ProductId":2,"ProductName":"Product 2","ProductDesc":"Description 2","EntityState":2,"EntityKey":{"EntitySetName":"tbl_product","EntityContainerName":"dbEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"ProductId","Value":2}],"IsTemporary":false}}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear why you defined the `Search.cshtml` partial when you controller action returns JSON. This partial will never be used. You could delete it.

Also since the id is unique I would recommend you modify your code to return a single result (`.First()` instead of `.Where()` which returns a collection):

```
public ActionResult Search(int data)
{
    var query = dbentity.tbl_product.First(c => c.ProductId == data);
    return Json(query);
}
```

and then in your success callback:

```
success: function (mydata) {
    alert("success");
    $('#link').html(mydata.ProductDesc);
},
```

This will display the `ProductDesc` property in the `<div>`. You also have access to all other properties as well. For example `mydata.ProductId` or `mydata.ProductName`.

There's also another problem with your code. It's the fact that `ids` in HTML cannot start with a number. Here you defined a link:

```
<a class="msg" href="#" id="@item.ProductId">@item.ProductName</a>
```

but the id is wrong as it cannot start with a number. I would recommend you using an HTML5 `data-*` attribute instead:

```
<a class="msg" href="#" data-id="@item.ProductId">@item.ProductName</a>
```

and in the .click javascript handler you could retrieve it like this in order to pass it to the AJAX call:

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
```

The alternative approach using a partial view instead of JSON is what I already showed you in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20173222/29407).

Comment: I have added this code $('#link').html(mydata.ProductDesc); but it returns nothing in the div neither the json, only alert(success) is executed

Comment: Did you also change your `Search` controller action to use `dbentity.tbl_product.First(c => c.ProductId == data);` instead of `dbentity.tbl_product.Where(c => c.ProductId == data);` as you had in initially? Please look more carefully at how the `Search` controller action is defined in my answer.

Comment: No, they are accessible without any problem. The Search controller action returns them as JSON result and you could access them all. I ask you once again: Did you replace `.Where(...)` with `.First(...)`?

Comment: Thanks Darin... It now works but i want to ask if this method is efficient or we can do it with partial view also. So that i can refresh partial view every time....

Comment: One point more, if i want to display the details of Product 1 by default when my view load,how it can be achieved.

Comment: You would achieve that more easily with a PartialView. Because you can use it to initially display using the Html.Partial helper.